# Is there HW module with ARM Cortex m3,4,7 and Canbus interface that could be used in smaller quantity project?

Tags: arm, can-bus, cortex-m

we are searching for the ARM-based module with CANBUS interface. Preferably ARM Cortex m4.
We would like to program it and use in smaller quantities for our projects as CAN extendable module boards.

Anyone aware of such modules (we've used Modtronix SBCxx some time ago, now we would like to refresh HW platform) ?

Thanks,
regards.

Comment: What did the major cortex-m based mcu vendors say when you called them?  st, ti, nxp, etc...

Comment: Most companies that manufacture Cortex-M4 based microcontrollers make one with CAN peripherals. Search the internet, but as @old_timer says look at ST, TI and NXP.

Comment: Hello, I know that majority of Cortex M4, M7 have CANBUS peripherals included... What I'm after are modules that are ready to be programmed and used as CANBUS nodes. I guess that some manufacturers are doing this...